# Does the arithmetic negate count as a floating point operation?

Tags: floating-point, flops

I'm currently measuring the performance of some code in FLOPS. This code presents some arithmetic negate instructions like this one:

```
d = -a
```

where `d` and `a` are floating point variables. **The architecture I'm currently using does have specific negate instructions.** Should I have to take into account this kind of operations to measure FLOPS? What kind of operations account for FLOPS? Is there a convention or anything?

Comment: How is measuring FLOPS on arbitary code useful?

Comment: @Jonas: it tells you how well you're utilizing the FPU units on your CPU. For computationally heavy programs, that can be a very good measurement of how much room there is for further optimization.

Comment: I'm benchmarking some algorithms, and I'm using FLOPS as a measure of the performance of these algorithms (comparing the performance achieved with the maximum FLOPS possible in the architecture I'm using).

Comment: The FLOPS number for your architecture was probably measured with LINPACK. I'm not at all sure that you really can compare an arbitary algorithm with LINPACK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrey said, to be sure you should check the disassembled code.

But in general, yes, the instruction would likely execute on a FPU. It simply flips a bit, so it *could* be done on an integer unit as well, but since you're operating on floating point values, these are most likely already loaded into FP registers, and so there'd be a fair amount of overhead to moving them to general purpose registers, flipping the bit and moving them back.

I don't know if there is a complete universal guide to "what should be counted as a FLOP", but this is most likely an instruction which executes on a FPU, and so it is competing with other FP instructions for resources on the CPU, so yes, I would include it in a FLOPS count.

Answer (score 3):

try to disassemble the code and check how this operation is performed.

if it uses instruction `FCHS` (Change sign) then you can consider it floating point operation.

MSVC (Visual Studio 2008)

```
    double c = -b;
00971397  fld         qword ptr [b] 
0097139A  fchs             
0097139C  fstp        qword ptr [c]
```

fchs - see that?

Comment: true, but note that he doesn't say he's running on x86

Comment: Yes, I know for sure there is a negate assembly instruction in the architecture the I'm using, I've already done that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a kind of convention to calculate the FLOPS using LINPACK as a kind of standard benchmark.